# Infinite number of invariant sets

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, set-invariance

Consider the system
\begin{align*}
     \dot{x} &= 2x+y\\
     \dot{y} &= x-y.
 \end{align*}
Prove that there exists an infinite number of invariant sets.

I do not know how to proceed. My first attempt was calculate the equilibrium point and analyzed its stability. But I do nos know how to conclude that the exist infinite invariant sets. Another approach I tried is prove that the line $y=kx$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is invariant, but I did not get anything.

Any help?

Comment: A good idea for getting some intuition behind a PDE is to plot its phase space flow. In this case, it looks like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=stream+plot+%7B2x%2By%2Cx-y%7D). Can you see the invariant sets? *Answer*: Basically, every single of the trajectories you see is an "invariant set". Importantly, trajectories do not cross each other because the solution of the PDE can be proven to be unique by [standard PDE theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: Then I need to calculate the flow, right?

Comment: Not really, it suffices to prove the uniqueness of the solution of this PDE. Because then it immediately follows that trajectories do not cross each other, i.e. trajectories are "invariant sets".

Comment: And this is true, since every linear differential equation has a unique solution. In fact, this solutions is $x(t)=e^{At}x_0$, right?

Comment: Yes, sounds right to me.

Comment: @Andreas What PDE?

Comment: @PierreCarre My bad, I meant ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the characteristic equation is
$$ \lambda^2-\lambda-3 =0 $$
which has two roots $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$. Let
$$ y=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2e^{\lambda_2t} $$
and then
$$ x=\dot y+y=c_1(1+\lambda_1)e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2(1+\lambda_2)e^{\lambda_2t}. $$
Now for $k$ which will be determined soon, one has
$$ kx-y=c_1(k+k\lambda_1-1)e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2(k+k\lambda_2-1)e^{\lambda_2t}. $$
Let $k+k\lambda_1-1=0$ give
$$ k=\frac{1}{1+\lambda_1} $$
and hence
$$ kx-y=c_2(k+k\lambda_2-1)e^{\lambda_2t}. $$
Noting that $e^{\lambda_2t}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, one can have that $y=kx$ is the invariant (the red line in the graph) and hence conclude an infinite number of invariant sets.
[image]

Comment: How do you conclude that there exist infinite number of invariant sets?

Comment: Take $c_=0$ and then you have $kx-y=0$.

Comment: Yes, but $k$ is a fixed value?

Comment: $k$ is fixed which is in the answer.